# Sign convention for angular velocities in 3D gear train

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, gears, machine-design

[image]

Consider a Humpage gear train shown above. We are viewing the gear train from right and gear B is rotating in clockwise direction. If we consider clockwise direction as positive what will be the sign conventions of gears D and C. Can you provide a reference for the same.

[image]

This is the question for your reference. They have considered the angular velocity of gears D and C positive here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the phrasing looks like a homework exercise.

Comment: Oh. Actual question is quite different. I will give the image of the question in case you need to refer it.

Comment: I think you're reading more into the question than it's asking for. I don't know of any way you can define CW or CCW as being positive or negative. The question just says "200 RPM" without a direction of rotation and asks for an output speed. The answer would be an RPM and whether H is rotating in the same direction as G or opposite.

Comment: Consider the axis gear B is rotating around is the "global axis", on which the CW and CCW are defined. Now, C & D are moving on a different axis which should be considered a "local axis", then the sign convention can be related out by looking at the motions on both sides of the interception point of the global and local axes - they shall agree for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I looked in some standard books but didn't find anything on the problem. I think generally such sign convention are not needed as most of the times we can predict the direction of the gear is CW or CCW. But in case of complex problems where we go pure for mathematical solution like in case of epicyclic gears, it would be an issue.

Comment: My rule is to always assume rotation is mathematically positive defined for math like problems such as this…if it‘s something other than that, it should be specifically mentioned.